# Issue with getting a VSCode extension to work (syntax highlighting for angular HTML template files)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Link to VSCode extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ghaschel.vscode-angular-html

Hi, I installed and enabled this extension for syntax highlighting for angular HTML template files, and it doesn't seem to work for me. Here's a screenshot

[image]

Does this work for anyone else?

Comment: Hi! I am the creator of this extension, I'd say to you it's probably related to another extension that may interfere with HTML syntax highlighting... Can you try to disable other extensions that might be interfering?

Comment: @ghaschel Hi! Thanks for your response. I just checked just now and found out that this extension interfered with yours: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lightning

Highlighting now works after the mention extension is disabled!

Comment: Great to know! Happy to help